# Can a directed graph be a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, computer-science

I've come across this terminology for "linearly independent paths"

> linearly  independent  path  is  any  path  through  the  program  that introduces  at least one new edge that is not included in any other linearly independent paths

is there a way to frame graphs as vector spaces?  I can sort of see how this idea is related, but I'm having trouble seeing how to add paths in a way that makes sense and it well-defined.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity

Comment: I don't know if directed graphs in general can be regarded as vector spaces, but there's a notion of independence that generalise that of vector spaces and it's used in graphs and other structures. This concept is introduced in the theory of [Matroids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid)

Comment: Well, I've just found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_space), which tells that the edge space is a vector space, so the answer should be yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are talking about power set of the set of vertices or edges. The power set of any set is a vector space over the finite field of order $2$. The addition operation is given by taking the symmetric difference.

$$A+B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$$
Scalar multiplication can really only be defined in one way.